# Google Apps script not working in an embedded iframe

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet where I have placed a few buttons linking to the script. It works fine when I use it on the sheets page. But when I publish it and embed the sheet on my website, the button doesn't work. It's not performing.
Below is the sample code I use to move from one sheet to another with the click of the button and the iframe code I am using.

```
function goToInward() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Inward"));
}

<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:55px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When you publish a a Google spreadsheet to the Web - it is view only access

- Indeed, if you type into your browser address bar the direct publish link:
  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false`,
  you will see that you likewise obtain only a view version of the spreadsheet
- You cannot perform edits in the spreadsheets, and consequently you cannot run an Apps Script - since the latter requires edit access

**WORKAROUND**

- When publishing a spreadsheet, you can specify in the URL which sheet shall be shown
- By default, it is the first sheet, but if you specofy e.g.
  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false#gid=yyyyyyyyy`,
  then the sheet with the sheet id `yyyyyyyyy` will be opened
- Consequently, you can create your own sheet changing script within your Website
- For this, simply create an html button and specify that on button click the user shall be redirected to the sheet

**Sample**

```js
    <iframe id="frame" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:55px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Change tabs</button>
    <script>
      function myFunction(){
        document.getElementById("frame").src = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pubhtml?widget=true&amp;headers=false#gid=yyyyyyyyy";
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But the sheet is not editable. It is looking like a plain image with no option to click and edit

Comment: The sheet is never editable if you use the version published to the web. If you want to edit it, you need to embed the actual sheet URL (not the publishing URL) into your website and set the sharing permissions accordingly. But this is already a different story.